# What does a triangle mean in chord notation?

Tags: chords, notation, chord-theory

For example, what does the △ mean in C△7?

Comment: Be careful with using CM for C major. In Inkpen, a popular font with users of the Sibelius score-publishing program, lower-case letters are merely small versions of upper-case ones, so CM could easily be confused with Cm. Use Cmaj7 or C^.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27465/why-delta-chords) and its answers. There the origin of the triangle (= triad!) is explained.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's a major 7th chord! C△7 would be C, E, G, and B♮.

Comment: Does that mean that it is the same as CM7?

Comment: Yes, it has the same meaning as a `M` or `maj`.

Comment: There is muddy-ness in practice when it comes to using the △ alone. I have seen scores (I mean fake-books) where C△ = CMajor7 (as played on the recording), and other times where they clearly wanted only CMajor (perhaps the 7th ends up clashing with the melody). Perhaps this can be attributed by errors in transcription. Perhaps the answer is that they intended only CMajor and sometimes the CMajor7 will also work.

Comment: can i find a list of these somewhere? I've seen chord notations that have a circle with a line through and others variations. I was thinking they probably relate to maj7, min7, dom7 and majMin7 but no idea what they are

Comment: @FinbarMaginn There are definitely googlable resources for that. The Jamey Abersold website has some good resources available for free, but they are usually about the scale matching the symbol, not the chord name. Ø7 is half-diminished 7th (contrasts with o = diminished).

Comment: @NReilingh Great, thanks for clarity around diminished - i didn't know what to search for and stumbled across this question

Comment: @NReilingh - that O with a line (can't type it!) just by itself is usually written for 'half diminished', or 'm7b5'. No need for '7'.

Comment: Right, it can only be half diminished if it includes the b7, so it's understood.

Answer (score 4):

The triangle also shows up in a common notation for minor major seventh chords. For example, **CmM7** can be written as **CΔ̲**. The underlined triangle seems to be a combination of the **C‒** notation for **Cm** and the **CΔ** notation for **CM7**.

This seems especially common, along with **C∅** instead of **Cm7♭5** for half-diminished chords, in hand-written charts. Less to write, and less information to process for improvisers reading the through the changes.