# Correct chord name for Am(maj7)add9?

Tags: chords, notation, chord-theory

Given the chord notes A-C-E-G#-B, what is the correct chord name assuming the song is in the key of Am?   It is an E/Am polychord and the dissonance between the C and the B is the sound I'm seeking, so simply writing this as E/A doesn't really work.  I could write it as Cmaj7#5/A, I suppose, but that looks weird.  I believe it is an Am(maj7) with an added ninth but I'm not sure exactly how to write this on a chord chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This chord is called Am maj9 ("A minor major 9"). On a chart it would often be written just a Am maj7, which describes the basic chord quality. The additional tension (9) would be left at the discretion of the musicians.

Note that major 7th chords are often written using the [triangle symbol Δ](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/27466/9724). This is also true for minor chords with a major seventh (and a major ninth): AmΔ7, or AmΔ9.

The modifier "add 9" is only used if the 7th scale degree is not part of the chord, e.g., Am(add9) being A-C-E-B.